# Proving that there is a sequence of $2023$ distinct integers such that the sum of the squares of any two consecutive terms is a perfect square itself

Tags: pythagorean-triples

How to prove the following problem?

> Prove that, there is a sequence of $2023$ distinct integers such that the sum of the squares of any two consecutive terms is a perfect square itself.

I tried with Pythagorean triple. I can generate a sequence but I can't conclude. Thanks.

e.g. $6, 8, 15, 20, 48, 64, \dots $

\begin{multline*}
Triples:\\
(6, 8, 10)\\ 
(8, 15, 17)\\
(15, 20, 25)\\
(20, 48, 52)\\
(48, 64, 80)\\
\dots
\end{multline*}

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried with Pythagorean triple. I can generate a sequence but I can't conclude. Thanks

Comment: Hint:Try a geometric progression.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. But not clear your hint.  Pythagorean triple can help to solve the problem?

Comment: Labeling the terms of your sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$, I see that $a_5 = 8a_1$ and $a_6=8a_2$. It seems to me that this observation makes the sequence able to continue as long as you want.

Comment: Hint: Suppose we have a sequence with $k$ terms. Show that if we multiply the entire sequence by $b$, then the property still holds. Hence, show that we can always find a sequence with $k+1$ terms, so we can induct to 2023.

Comment: @RajansahaRaju Robert's hint is great! What condition is needed for 2 terms of a geometric progression to satisfy your condition? And how can we make that work out? In fact, all that we need is 1 pythagorean triple (and make modifications from there) $\quad$ FWIW My hint encompasses his hint (but his is a much simplier/direct observation).

Comment: @CalvinLin:  I initially read it to be $2023$ consecutive integers, not a sequence that need not even be monotonic.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah. For a moment, I thought that variant was an interesting question, then I realized that we can only have 2 consecutive integers in such a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

**Some Notations**

Define $I_{m}$ as a sequence of strictly increasing integers of length $m$:

$$
I_{m}=x_{1,m},x_{2,m},...,x_{m,m}
$$

such that $x_{i-1,m}^{2}+x_{i,m}^{2}$ is a perfect square for $i\in\{2,...,m\}$.

**Recursive Sequence Generation**

We generate the sequence $I_{m+1}$ as the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{m+1}&=x_{1,m+1}, x_{2,m+1}, ..., x_{m+1,m+1}
\\\\
x_{i,m+1}&=
\begin{cases}
x_{i,m}\cdot x_{m-1,m} & i=1,2,...,m \\
x_{m,m}^{2} & i = m+1,
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

The process is based on the followings:

- If $x_{i-1,m}^{2}+x_{i,m}^{2}$ is a perfect square, then so is $\left(x_{i-1,m}\cdot x_{m-1,m}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{i,m}\cdot x_{m-1,m}\right)^{2}$
- If $x_{m-1,m}^{2}+x_{m,m}^{2}$ is a perfect square, then so is $\left(x_{m,m}\cdot x_{m-1,m}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{m,m}\cdot x_{m,m}\right)^{2}$
- Since $x_{m,m}>x_{m-1,m}$, the sequence $I_{m+1}$ is also strictly increasing

Using the process, one can generate an arbitrarily long strictly increasing (hence distinct) sequence of integers such that the sum of square of any two consecutive is a perfect square. As an example:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{2}&=3,4\\
I_{3}&=9,12,16\\
I_{4}&=108, 144, 192, 256\\
&\vdots
\end{aligned}
$$

**Remarks**

Of course this is not the most elegant way to solve the problem, as the sequence become too large, but hey it does the trick

Comment: FYI This was condensely expressed by Robert's hint of "Try a geometric progression".

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah my bad, I didn't see the comment section beforehand

Comment: For slower growth, try$$x_{i,m+1}=
\begin{cases}
x_{i,m}\cdot x_{1,2} & i=1,2,...,m \\
x_{m,m}\cdot x_{2,2} & i = m+1,
\end{cases}$$
This gives what I first understood from the "geometric progression" comment, just explicitly as $x_{i,m} = 3^{m-1}(4/3)^{i-1}$.

Comment: @peterwhy very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We begin with Euclid's formula
$\quad A=m^2-k^2 \quad B=2mk \quad C=m^2+k^2.\quad$

For the sum of squares of any two consecutive terms to equal a square, each alternate odd or even number, except for the first, must participate in at least two triples. For example:
$\,(5,12,13), (35,12,37)\,$ begins the sequence
$\,\{5,12,35,612,1075,23100,16571,\cdots\}.\quad$ In a Pythagorean triple, Side-$A\,$ can be any odd number greater than one and side-$B\,$ can be any multiple of $\,4.\quad$ Beginning with $\,A=5,\,$ and given $\,(5,12,13)\,$ we can find $\,B=12\,$ triples using the formula by solving for $\,k\,$ and testing a defined range of $\,m$=values.  Any value of $\,m\,$ that yields an integer yields an $\,(m,k)\,$ pair we seek.

$$B=2mk\implies k=\frac{B}{2m}
\quad\text{ for }\quad \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{2B+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \frac{B}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $m\ge 2$
$$B=12\implies\qquad \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{24+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor =3 \le m \le \frac{12}{2}=6\\
 \text{ and we find} \quad m\in\{3,6\}\implies k\in\{2,1\}$$
$$F(3,2)=(5,12,13)\qquad F(6,1)=(35,12,37)$$

Beginning with $\,(35,12,37),\,$ we can find another side-$A$ using

$$A=m^2-k^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-A}\quad\text{for}\quad  \sqrt{A+1} \le m \le \frac{A+1}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k$.
$$A=35\implies \sqrt{35+1}=6\le m \le 
\frac{35+1}{2} =18\\
\text{ and we find}\quad m\in\{6,18\}\implies k \in\{1,17\} $$
$$F(6,1)=(35,12,37)\qquad F(18,17)=(35,612,613) $$

This process can be repeated (alternately find A and B triple) indefinitely so there are more than 2023 numbers where the sum of squares of any two consecutive terms is also a square. The numbers can get quite large but sometimes the numbers decrease as shown in the last term of the example sequence.

If we allow ourselves to be trivial, there are also infinite sequences such as
$\quad 5,12,35,12,35,12,35,12,35,\cdots$ that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @poetasis What will be the sequence then?

Comment: @Calvin Lin I have edited my answer to reflect a new sequence.

Comment: @Rajan saha Raju I have edited my answer to reflect a new sequence.

Comment: While I get how you're wanting to extend the sequence, the steps isn't clear to me. EG when you say $ 3 \leq m \leq 6$ how did you jump to $ m \in \{ 3, 6 \}$, and also why $ k \in \{ 1, 1\}$?  None of this is explained in the prior line, so can you elaborate on the algorithm? $\quad$ FWIW I know that this approach can work, I'm just saying I don't easily understand what you're doing in the writeup.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I have edited my answer showing that, solving for $k$, any $m$-value that yields an integer gives us the $(m,k)$ values for a triple we seek.

Comment: Right, so show that directly. EG Given a pair $ (A, B)=(m^2-k^2, 2 mk)$ with $k \neq 1$ and $m$ even, we can form  $(m', k') = (mk, 1)$ giving $(B, A) = (2mk, (mk)^2 - 1)$. Likewise, given a pair $(B, A) = (2mk, m^2 - k^2)$ with $k = 1$ and $m$ even, we can form  $(m', k') = (m^2/2, m^2/2 - 1)$ giving $(A,B) = (m^2 - 1, m^4/2-m^2 ) $.